# I can't get Opencv aruco to work on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, opencv

I've tried to install cv2 on my raspberry pi and when I run just `import cv2` in python it executes fine but when I run `import cv2.aruco`

If it's relevant, I have a raspberry pi 1b (the original one with 2 usb ports not 4)

I am met with this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.aruco'
```

to install opencv I ran the following:

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

I would appreciate any advice for where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: please try to share code snippet so we can review it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still having this issue:

In order to make opencv-contrib work on Raspi there are two thing you need:

You shouldn’t have the standard opencv installed

And then:

A specific version needs to be installed, you can find what is the most recent version that works on this website:
https://www.piwheels.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/
Once you’ve found a version that works (one with a green tick for your OS)

You can install that specific version using this command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.3.56
```

Just change the number to the most recent working version

I followed this tutorial:
https://singleboardblog.com/install-python-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

The `opencv-contrib-python` requires the `opencv-contrib-python` add-on package to OpenCV. A `pip install opencv-contrib-python` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried that now but it gets 'Killed' at 100% with this error message: `Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-contrib-python 
  Downloading opencv-contrib-python-4.7.0.72.tar.gz (150.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 150.5 MB 1.1 MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed`

Comment: This error can happen when the system runs out of usable RAM. Try appending `--no-cache-dir` to your `pip install` and closing all other running programs.